# Highcharts: More space between line and bottom of chart

Tags: highcharts

screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1O0tn.jpg

if you take a look at my chart here, you can see that the bottom of the line for values on or near 0 are partially obscured by the bottom of the chart. This is because I have the 'floor' of the yAxis set on 0, otherwise I'll get a '-1000 words' legend on the left. If there some way I can add a bit of space there, between the line and bottom of the chart?

Or, disable negative values for the legend? All I've found is setting 'min' or 'floor' on the yAxis to 0.

Cheers.

Comment: you can set specific padding /margin in chart using chart:{
    spacingTop: 20, //spacing from top
    spacingLeft: 20,
    spacingRight: 10,
    spacingBottom: 20,//spacing from bottom , set it with desired value
    margin: //margin you need
}

Comment: You can try to set [minPadding on yAxis](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.minPadding)